# Residual-analysis by running KNN or Clustering on incorrect ANN or RF predictions?

Tags: clustering, random-forest, prediction, residuals

I've outputs of some neutral net models, which naturally gives some errors in the prediction. What I am interested in is determining whether there are any systemic patterns associated with these incorrect predictions.

My thinking is that being able to characterize incorrect predictions will help me in indentifying risk. For example I was thinking of finding subsets of the incorrect predictions and using something like clustering.

Is there any procedure already implemented to do this type of work? Or conversely is there any reason it is a bad idea?

Comment: Pity the downvoter didn't explain what their issue was so you could fix it. Your question is vague, could you be more precise about your underlying intent? It sounds reasonable on a vague level but for someone to answer coherently they need a better defined situation. I'll try an edit and you can reject or ammend as you see fit.

Comment: @ReneBt A questionable downvote is easily cured. Just up vote, like I did. With respect to models, when they do not work well enough to be useful, they need fixing/replacement with better models.

Comment: I have added residuals and residual-analysis as some keywords. I think your problem is much like this. I have not voted to close your question, but I would agree that it is borderline on being broad. Studying residuals or the wrongly classified cases is very broad (and maybe more like an art than science). I removed the r-tag since I do not see any use for it. You have not mentioned any link with R in the question.